# Error: {"message": "user.check is not a function" } in postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

There Is My Code ~

```
    const user = new User(req.body, rules);
    const matched = await user.check();
    if (!matched) {
      return res.status(404).send(user.errors)
    }
```

I'm fairly new to Node.js and I am having some issues.

May I know what is wrong with my code?

Comment: guess the User class is relevant to share

Comment: The problem with the code is that `User` does not contain a function `check`. `check` is either a variable which you would acces like `user.check` without parentheses. If it is a function, you have either not defined it or you are misstyping its name. With the current code example we cannot conclude if either of these things is the cause of the error.